# need perl script to find count of images found in web log

Tags: perl, web, counter

I have web log files and I was having a lot of trouble, being new with perl. I just need a script to find a count of each of the images that were found. I was able to list them but I'm unsure of how to just get a count, say something like "There were x jpgs and x gifs viewed".

My code so far looks like this:

```
use warnings;
open FILE, "jan28.log";
while ($line = <FILE>) { 

    if ($line =~ /.jpg/) {

        print $line;
    } 
    elsif ($line =~ /.gif/) {

        print $line;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /tiff/) {

        print $line; 
    }
}
```

The web logs look like this.

```
24.131.83.162 - - [28/Jan/2007:00:00:00 -0500] "GET /~taler/images/index_09.jpg   HTTP/1.1" 200 1563
207.46.98.53 - - [28/Jan/2007:00:00:04 -0500] "GET /%7Edist/programs/PhD/PhDGuide/guideA.htm HTTP/1.0" 200 19090
74.6.74.184 - - [28/Jan/2007:00:00:12 -0500] "GET /%7Embsclass/hall_of_fame/myicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200 760
58.68.24.3 - - [28/Jan/2007:00:00:16 -0500] "GET /~dtipper/tipper.html HTTP/1.1" 200 5896
58.68.24.3 - - [28/Jan/2007:00:00:16 -0500] "GET /~dtipper/gifs/head.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 18318
```

Comment: Do you want to share the script you wrote?

Comment: @Vikdor All i had was this 'use warnings;

open FILE, "jan28.log";

while ($line=<FILE>){
if ($line=~/.jpg/){
print $line;
}elsif ($line=~/.gif/){
 print $line;
}elsif ($line=~/tiff/){
 print $line;
}
}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use URI qw( );

my $jpegs = 0;
my $gifs  = 0;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($req, $code) = /^(?:\S+\s+){3}\[[^\]]*\] "([^"]*)"\s*(\S+)/
      or next;

   $code >= 200 && $code < 300
      or next;

   my ($meth, $url) = split(' ', $req);
   $url = URI->new($url, 'http');

   my $path = $url->path;
   if    ($path =~ /\.jpe?g\z/i) { ++$jpegs; }
   elsif ($path =~ /\.gif\z/i  ) { ++$gifs; }
}

say "There were $jpegs jpgs and $gifs gifs viewed";
```

Comment: You have an error in the last line, $jpeg is never declared and URI is not loaded.

Comment: Moreover, jpg count is wrong. It founds only 1, there's 2...

Comment: Thank you for your help! @sputnick, I'm sure your answer was correct also, but I did not understand it much, I apologize

Comment: @sputnick, No, it finds 2 for the input given by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this (in a shell) :

```
perl -wane '
    END{
        print "there\047s was $hash{$_} items for $_\n" for sort keys %hash;
    }

    $key = $1 if m!.*\.(jpe?g|gif|ico)\b!i;
    $hash{$key}++
' filename.txt
```

If you want a real script with the same logic, the `Deparse` module will helps :

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -wane '
END{
    print "there\047s was $hash{$_} items for $_\n" for sort keys %hash;
}

$key = $1 if m!.*\.(jpe?g|gif|ico)\b!i;
$hash{$key}++
' filename.txt
```

"Deparsed" result script :

```
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    our(@F) = split(' ', $_, 0);
    sub END {
        print "there's was $hash{$_} items for $_\n" foreach (sort keys %hash);
    }
    $key = $1 if /.*\.(jpe?g|gif|ico)\b/i;
    ++$hash{$key};
}
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: Incorrect extension extracted for `/foo.gif?a=b` and for `/foo.cgi?name=foo.gif`. Doesn't work for HTTP/0.9 requests. Incorrectly reports non-existent images as being viewed. Reports all extension and not just the two requested. Considered `.GIF` and `.gif` to be different.

Comment: POST edited and script modified to deal only with jp(e)g, gif and ico. Moreover,  I reply only to the OP demands, I don't wrote the whole exclusions it can needs.

Comment: Just documenting the numerous limitations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example, but there is probably some Log Parser module in CPAN.

```
use File::Open::OOP qw(oopen);
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $fh = oopen 'log';
my %hash;
while ( my $row = $fh->readline ) {
  $row =~ s/.*\"GET\ \/.*\.(\w+)\ .*\n$/$1/;
  $ext = $row;
  $hash{$ext} += 1;
}
dump(%hash);
```

Output for your sample:

$ perl script.pl

("html", 1, "ico", 1, "jpg", 2, "htm", 1)

$